# i'm able to create raidz with diff sized of hard disk. where im missing?

Tags: freebsd, zfs, raidz

i read about raidz5 cannot create with diff sizes of hard disks but i'm able to create raidz with diff sized of hard disk please tell me where im missing?

```
da0              0:107  12G zfs                                   - -
da1              0:109 8.0G zfs                                   - -
md0              0:13  456M ufs                                   - /
vtbd0            0:53   80G GPT                                   - /
  vtbd0p1        0:115 512K freebsd-boot       gptid/681ee6a8-6ab8-11eb-b72e-558e06157d17 -
  <FREE>         -:-   492K -                                     - -
  vtbd0p2        0:122 2.0G freebsd-swap                  gpt/swap0 -
  vtbd0p3        0:127  78G freebsd-zfs                   gpt/disk0 <ZFS>
  <FREE>         -:-   1.0M -                                     - -
```

```
  pool: edjstorage
 state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:

    NAME         STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    edjstorage   ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz1-0   ONLINE       0     0     0
        vtbd0p3  ONLINE       0     0     0
        da0      ONLINE       0     0     0
        da1      ONLINE       0     0     0
```

Comment: What does `zpool list` give as the size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the fact that the various component devices used size will be rounded down to the smallest capacity - ie: supposing you create a RAIDZ with 3x 2TB disks and 1x 1TB disk, total pool capacity (including parity overhead) will be 4x 1TB (or 3TB excluding parity).

Similarly, a 2-way mirror between 1x 2TB disk and 1x 1TB disk will end with only 1TB usable capacity.